# Is Android's STT based on the same technology as the Google Cloud Speech API?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Seeing as they are both part of Google, what is the difference between [Android SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) and the [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)? Do they utilise the same technology/models? Has anyone reviewed performance differences?

Comment: same question. did find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894457/difference-between-android-speech-to-text-api-recognizer-intent-and-google-clo