# Android Speech to Text Api Google - notification

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I followed this tuto:
https://jbinformatique.com/2018/02/16/android-speech-to-text-api-google-tutoriel/

It works nice ! It uses android.speech.RecognizerIntent package
it's free and it works without Internet as mentionned here:

[Difference between Android Speech to Text API (Recognizer Intent) and Google Cloud Speech API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894457/difference-between-android-speech-to-text-api-recognizer-intent-and-google-clo)

However when I start the speech recognition, I get the following notification :

[image]

If I translate (as I can..), it says : "Your audio records will be sent to Google and used for speech recognition. Transcription will be shared with this application. File recorded on "....@gmail.com"

I thought that speech recognition was processed in local....Moreover it works without internet... so is this notification true ? Or must I add something in code to be sure that no data are sent to Google ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's SpeechRecognizer is only an interface to the speech recognition engine installed in the system and chosen as the default. For example, the default Google's recognizer supports both online and offline modes. When the internet connection is present, it sends raw data to and obtains the final result from the Google's internal cloud recognition service, hence the privacy warning on your screenshot. When there is no internet connection, it uses some proprietary on-board recognizer.

My general advise is to use a speech recognition system that you completely trust to if you are concerned about the privacy of the users' speech input.

Comment: Thank's a lot @Alexander... and I suppose there is no free internal system that works on android (may be on Linux)

Comment: There's at least one - [pocketsphinx-anroid](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android), but its performance is very limited comparing to cloud services. And this is in general true for all on-board systems. Please, accept my answer if you found it helpful.